# Awkward title page with Polyglossia in Beamer with Madrid theme

Tags: beamer, titles, polyglossia, themes

Using `Polyglossia` with `Madrid` theme produces an awkward title page heading.

**MWE1 - Working fine without the `Madrid` theme:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%:Language
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%:Hebrew Main
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\title{Alexander}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE1]

**MWE2 - Awkward title page heading with the `Madrid` theme:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
%:Language
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%:Hebrew Main
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\title{Alexander}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]

Comment: I wouldn't expect that everything in beamer works with bidi. You can make a bug report, but correcting this would be a long term project, so better avoid fancy effects like shadows for now.

Comment: How do I make a bug report, who do I send it to?

Comment: either bidi (but this seems to be unmaintained now) or beamer. But probably it would be better to try babel and its bidi support first. babel is maintained, so chances to get something corrected in bidi support are better.

Comment: There's no chance I am going back to Babylon. I just suppressed the shadows.

Comment: what do you have against babel?

Comment: I used babel (LaTeX) extensively in the past. At first I was reluctant to use Polyglossia  which forced me use XeLaTeX (which seemed unattractive for me at first). The advantages are: (1) using fontspec allows for a wide variety of fonts. (2) After defining the main language the code gets much shorter and simpler (for instance in Babel when I use Tikz I have to define the environment as "English" and inside it every word or paragraph has to be assigned an appropriate language tag). (3) There are further issues but these are the main issues I have encountered.

Comment: xelatex/lualatex/fontspec works with babel too, and assigning language is not different to polyglossia (actually babel has quite a number of tools to detect the language automatically). And babel+bidi+lualatex is much better than in polyglossia.

Comment: I will happy to learn. Can you refer me to some basic guides/questions regarding the use of lualatex (which I have never used before), with babel and fontspec?.

Comment: simply search e.g. for babel and hebrew, looks for answers using `bidi=basic`, \babelprovide and \babelfont.

Comment: @Morzen Have a look at `beamer-lr`, too: https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer-rl?lang=en

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have discovered a whole new world thanks to you. Admittedly I have not yet been able to produce a simple document, but I will read some more and eventually learn it. Your recommendation is excellent.

Comment: @Morzen Here is an example for Arabic: https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/master/samples/lua-beamer.tex . The result is: https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/master/samples/lua-beamer.pdf .

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in beamer for non-standard fonts, which has been fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/a3de6ba737d98746a60759a1d0b5c3c23c3879f1

(see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/678 for details)

[image]